# Querying mongoDB using the mlab data API

Tags: java, android, mongodb, mlab

im trying to extract a single document through a manually coded variable.
So here I am trying to find a document with the fields `name=siteName`.

```
    String baseUrl = String.format("https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/%s/collections/%s?q=",DB_NAME,COLLECTION_SITE_NAME );
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(baseUrl);
    try {
    String first = URLEncoder.encode("{","UTF-8");
    String second = URLEncoder.encode("}","UTF-8");
    String point = URLEncoder.encode(":","UTF-8");
    String URL = first+"\"name\""+point+siteName+second;
    stringBuilder.append(URL);
stringBuilder.append("&apiKey="+API_KEY);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more detail about what you are trying to achieve / what behaviour / error messages you get

Comment: i don't have error messages. when i can't get the document with the {"name": siteName}. i get null object. i followed the mlab document but it seems that i have sth wrong in my URL !!!!!
https://docs.mlab.com/data-api/